# perfocrce (p4) ; error deleting Perforce worksplace

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am having problem deleting Perforce workspace?

Even i am using P4V gui i am getting Error,

workspace has files opened.( p4 client -d user_workspace)

Client 'user_workspace' has files opened; use -f to force delete.

Comment: Revert your opened files, then you can delete your workspace.

Comment: You've got a typo in the title of your question (perfocrce instead of perforce).  You may have better results if you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a workspace with any changelists associated with it.  Here's how to clear the changes or move them so you can delete the workspace:

1. Look at the pending changelist view
2. Find the changes associated with your workspace you want to delete (use the filter if there are too many to sort)
3. Either revert files in the changelists or shelve the files and associate the changelists with another workspace to clear them from the workspace to be deleted
4. Verify that the workspace is not locked, or unlock it if needed.

Now you should be able to delete the workspace.

Comment: There are also two parts to deleting a work space.  After clearing items per the answer above you need to delete the server instance of the work space and the local file system work space.  Deleting the work space off the server does not remove the local files.

Comment: By deleting the workspace I was referencing the P4 workspace, which lives on the P4 server.  It's just a spec mapping files to your local computer.  In P4, when you "delete a workspace", it prompts you with "You are about to delete Workspace 'my_workspace' from the server. Are you sure you want to continue?"  Deleting the files from a local drive is not the same as deleting a workspace.